# Batch file if then statement from user input

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Brand new here, and brand new to scripting. So, I'm struggling with this and I know I shouldn't be.

I have a batch file that currently scans and unpacks zip files. All I'm trying to do is add an input line for Business Date at the top that can then be referenced in the unpacking to make sure the dates are correct. Here is the file as it exists (I've added the user input just don't know how to reference it):

```
echo off
:Ask
echo Please enter Business Date (MMDDYYY)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%


c:
cd\502
erase *.prn
7z e "\\svr-dc\ftp site\502\daily\data1.zip"
copy sz*.* sales.xls
copy sc*.* cosales.xls
copy aj*.* money.xls
copy cc*.* count.xls
pause
```

Instead of a pause there I would like for the file to run through all the directories, they are 502 to 607, and tell me whether the filename listed in the *.* is the same as the user entered business date. Then, run through the rest of the directories doing the same thing. Once it's verified that I'd like to have a .txt file open with any business dates that didn't match. Does that make any sense? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Comment: How can the batch identify the desired files? What is the `rest of the directories`?  What are `business dates that didn't match`?

Comment: All of the files that are unzipped are szMMDDYYY sales.xls and so on.  I'm trying to verify that these files were updated while running this batch file instead of hitting return on every pause.

Comment: Sorry, the rest of the directories are similarly labeled, 502, 503, 504 and so on through 607.

Comment: It was a typo, sorry.  It should be YYYY to represent a 4 digit year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
c:
FOR /L %%X in (502,1,607) DO (
 cd\%%X
 erase *.prn
 7z e "\\svr-dc\ftp site\%%X\daily\data1.zip"
 copy sz*.* sales.xls
 copy sc*.* cosales.xls
 copy aj*.* money.xls
 copy cc*.* count.xls
)
```

You would use `%input%` to access the value that was entered as INPUT, but you give no clue to how `"to make sure the dates are correct."`

---

Hmm - given further information (perhaps...)

```
...
c:
FOR /L %%X in (502,1,607) DO (
 cd\%%X
 erase *.prn
 7z e "\\svr-dc\ftp site\%%X\daily\data1.zip"
 if exist sz%input%*.prn ( 
  copy sz*.* sales.xls
  copy sc*.* cosales.xls
  copy aj*.* money.xls
  copy cc*.* count.xls
 ) else (
  echo Repoll %%X First>>C:\Users\Boster\Desktop\RePoll.txt
 )
)
```

It's critical that the `(` occurs on the same physical line as the `if` and that `) else (` all appears on the same physical line.

Comment: Okay, let me try to be more clear.  All of the files that are copied, the sz*.* are dated files.  The actual file name for today for instance would be sz07222013.prn.  I'm trying to cerify all of those filenames against the date that is input by the user at the beginning.  Thanks for the clarification on the for loop!

Comment: Since it won't let me post in here again with enough room to show the code I have updated it to what is close.  It's still outputting every time regardless of the date entered.  `code`if EXIST sz%input% .prn (
 copy sz*.* sales.xls
 ) ELSE (
 echo Repoll %%X First>>C:\Users\Boster\Desktop\RePoll.txt.
 )

Answer (score 0):

You asked a couple of question so instead of writing one batch script I thought I should break it down to explain how it would answer your questions:

1- Use `%INPUT%` to reference your variable/user input

2- If you will always have 502 to 607, then you can loop through them using a for loop
`FOR /L %%G IN (502,1,607) DO echo %%G`

3- To check if there exist a file/folder with the same value as the user input use an `if EXIST %INPUT%` statement

There are quite a few tutorials out there, here is one that walks you through [batch file scripting](http://commandwindows.com/batch.htm)

Comment: That's great input thanks.  With your point 3 though, how do I get the bat file to tell me if one of the dates is not correct?  This is supposed to be verifying that the files have updated.

Comment: Sorry, if you look at the input it's asking for a date in the format of MMDDYYY.  The files themselves are called szMMDDYYYsales.xls and the like.  I need for it to check the date in the middle of that file name so and spit out whether or not it's incorrect.  I've got it to the point that it's printing to a txt file but I can't seem to get it to force that verification, it just prints every time.  Here is the updated code that I've worked out to get me to this point.  I'm gonna work in the for Loop once I've got the single site worked out.